# Codename One - all available BrowserComponent properties

Tags: codenameone

About the BrowserComponent properties, in the API it's written so:

```
 public void setProperty(java.lang.String key, java.lang.Object value)
```

*This method allows customizing the properties of a web view in various ways including platform specific settings. When a property isn't supported by a specific platform it is just ignored.*

Where are listed all available properties, including platform specific settings?

Thank you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no official list. We use this method to workaround platform specific issues and never compiled a list of what's available. On Android we use reflection to the underlying browser implementation so it varies based on what Google does in their internal component. That's why we can't document it, once we do we will need to support that.